# Angular workflow node with forms

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, workflow

I am seeking for the workflow nodes with forms when user click on it.
I found few however not all are open sources.
please guide me as i am seeking for open sources (simple and basics)

below is what i have found

- https://github.com/optimajet/workflow-designer-angular-sample - license
- https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-designer - deprecated..
- https://github.com/joelvh/flowy-engine/tree/master#import-the-flowchart-data
- https://nodered.org/ - too advance

currently we are looking for in angular but not limited can consider others like nodejs, react or vue as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want basic functionality you can use this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rssocg-tutkpk?file=main.ts

From my side i need advanced functionality then they exist in the above link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35842361)